# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv' Exiting due to failure, even after virtual environment is successfully installed for AWS EBCLI

Tags: python-3.x

I had installed AWS EB cli and I am trying to run the bundled installer using "$ .\aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup\scripts\bundled_installer" below is the error I am getting not sure of addressing it.

```
1. Installing virtualenv
************************
Collecting virtualenv
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/ee/8375c01412abe6ff462ec80970e6bb1c4308724d4366d7519627c98691ab/virtualenv-16.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-16.6.0

==============================================
II. Creating self-contained EBCLI installation
==============================================
Installing the EBCLI in C:\Users\xxcsds\.ebcli-virtual-env

******************************************
1. Creating exclusive virtualenv for EBCLI
******************************************

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\xxcsds\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py",
> line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>     "__main__", mod_spec)   File "c:\users\xxcsds\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py",
> line 85, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup\scripts\virtualenv\bin\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py",
> line 5, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv'
> Exiting due to failure
```

Comment: This is a problem with the script in how it's trying to install `virtualenv`. You should report this issue [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/) for a quicker response.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug in way AWS EBCLI is installed

https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/issues/19

use below commands

```
pip uninstall -y virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
python .\aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup\scripts\ebcli_installer.py
```

Comment: Such a life-saver

Answer (score 2):

I've just run into the same problem. It's just workaround but you can install AWS EBCLI on virtual environment [like described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-virtualenv.html). Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to `pip install awsebcli` in the venv that I was working in to get things up and running.